# Accessing Moose object in package to be called explicitly outside

Tags: perl, moose

for a Moose package, I am trying to create a object in Perl (non-moose) and then trying to access a method outside. Code to explain this situation is here.

```
package person;
{
    use Moose;
    sub test {
        print "my test print";
    }
}

package people {
    use person;
    my $obj = person->new();
}

$people::obj->test()
```

I am getting following Error on executing this perl code.

```
Can't call method "test" on an undefined value at test.pm
```

Am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never assigned anything to `$people::obj`. You assigned something to an unrelated lexical var named `$obj`, a variable that doesn't even exist by the time the program reaches the method call. Lexical vars (e.g. those created by `my`) are scoped to the innermost curlies in which they are located, which is to say they are only visible (accessible) there.

Fix:

```perl
package Person;
{
    use Moose;

    sub test {
        print "my test print";
    }
}

package People {
    my $obj = person->new();

    sub get_person {
       return $obj;
    }
}

People->get_person->test();
```

Notes:

- Removed `use person;` which either prevented the program from compiling, or unintentionally executed some potentially-conflicting code.
- Lowercase module names are reserved for pragmas.
- I could have have changed the lexical variable into a package variable, but using global variable is a bad practice. Using a method (or sub) can make things a lot easier in the future.
- Be careful putting multiple packages/classes in one file. There are pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to use `$obj` as a global variable and use it outside the package, you have to define it as such with `our`. Changing

```
    my $obj = person->new();
```

to

```
    our $obj = person->new();
```

and your script works. But using globals - even via getters as ikegami proposed - is often a bad idea.